# How to convert ethereum addres to public key

Tags: python, ethereum, public-key

I need to convert ethereum address like this

0xB34080739D5B656D76089f9f21b374BA5dafA373

to public key like this

e2d3a3a43e71eb541e12504cee22ed74024969b46b9e68ea7f9e5384fe96fc04

I got the address this way

```
from web3 import Web3

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://sokol.poa.network'))

addr = w3.toHex(w3.sha3(text=public_key)[12:])
```

Maybe there is a library for that? help pls

Comment: It's not as impossible as everyone says.  It can be done with a signature made by that address. and the signed data.  I don't have exact algorithm at this moment but if you search elsewhere you will find it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible.

An ethereum address (for an externally owner account, which is an account linked to a private key) is the last 20 bytes of `keccak256(public_key)`. Since `keccak256` is a hash function, and thus a one-way function, there is no way to recover the public key from the address.

Answer (score 0):

**Private key:** Only the owner/account holder knows about it .It is a 256bits number (64Hexadecimal digits each 4 bits).

The range of your private key is a number between 1 to 2^256 .(This is a massive number to imagine).
When you create an account in a wallet ,for example: **Metamask** , it will take some manual inputs from the user while creating the account . This may be in the form of mouse hovering metadata , click the image pattern etc .

This random input in the form of random bits will be fed to a keccak256 hash algorithm, which will produce a 256bit number . This is your **private key**.

Note : Any input to keccak256 will produce a 256bit number. No matter how big or small. keccak256 is a **one way hash function** that maps data of random size to a 256bit number. It is impossible to recreate the input data if one knows only the output hash.

**Public key :**

This is generated from a one way function using the formula

**K** = k*G.

k is your private key and G is a generator point in the elliptical curve . This is not a linear multiplication.

**Ethereum address** :
The public key is fed to the keccak256 algorithm again ,and then we keep only last 20 bytes (least significant bit) which is in the form of a 42-character hexadecimal address and ***this is our ethereum address***.

Example : 0x**743FF9a3238aB503dEd960f9317542bAf9cd418C**

Extracting private key from ethereum address is impossible in any scenario imagined and so is to convert ethereum addres to public key.

Cheers

Comment: What if you have a signature made by the address and the signed message ??